# Implementation of a condition in a Function

Tags: conditional

I have defined that 
stoptime
{5, 2, 10, 2, 1, 11, 11, 1, 5, 11}

and have the following function
pvcosts = (-5/1.05^#) &[stoptime]

Now I want that everytime "stoptime" is 11, the function gets zero.
I already thought about modifiying "stoptime", but I want it to stay the way it is.

How can I include a condition, that everytime "stoptime" is 11, "pvcosts" gets zero?

Thanks for your help

Comment: maybe `pvcosts = If[# == 11, 0, (-5/1.05^#)] & /@ stoptime` ?

Comment: yes! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Note that `Power` and `Times` have the attribute `Listable`, you can thus e.g. do:

```
x^# &[Range[10]]
```

or (the same)

```
Power[x, Range[10]]
```

to get:

> {x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6, x^7, x^8, x^9, x^10}

Thus, you can apply your function `pvccosts` on `stoptime` directly.

In my suggestion (in the comments):

```
pvcosts = If[# == 11, 0, (-5/1.05^#)] & /@ stoptime
```

the function is not `Listable` (as `If` isn't), and thus I `Map` (a.k.a. `/@` the function on `stoptime`.

We get:

> {-3.91763, -4.53515, -3.06957, -4.53515, -4.7619, 0, 0, -4.7619, \
>   -3.91763, 0}

Answer (score 3):

A general approach is to use the function `Piecewise`. You might define your function:

```
pv[x_] = Piecewise[{{0, x == 11}}, -5/1.05^x]
```

which says that if the input is 11, make the output 0, otherwise make it -5/1.05^x. You can call this with your stoptime

```
pv/@stoptime
```

which gives the answer you expect.

Another way to do this is to define the function

pvcost[x_] = -5/1.05^x

but then define an additional value (that at 11)

pvcost[11] = 0

Now, when you apply `pvcost`, it will evaluate using the formula. But whenever the specific value 11 is encountered, it will give output 0. The general rule about such things is that more specific definitions override the more generic.